# Stringified Json inside unstringified Json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, ionic-framework

I got a simple yet big problem.

The replied JSON I got is something like this:

```
{
    "responseCode":200,
    "response":"{\"success\":true,\"results\":[{\"_id\":\"57907ca4dc2a4ff43c6d1300\",\"user_email\":\"testuser9@hotmail.com\",\"user_displayName\":\"auauau\",\"user_gender\":2,\"user_registerDate\":\"2016-07-21T07:41:24.748Z\",\"user_timezone\":\"-540\",\"__v\":0,\"updatedOn\":\"2016-07-22T02:20:44.624Z\"\,\"user_images\":{\"avatarSmall\":\"n/a\",\"avatarLarge\":\"n/a\",\"coverSmall\":\"n/a\",\"coverLarge\":\"n/a\"},\"user_birthDate\":{\"status\":false,\"dateAndTime\":\"1994-12-01T07:00:00.000Z\"}}]}",
    "headers":{
    }
}
```

As you can see, the JSON I got is no doubt a JSON.

However, the inside `myJson.response` is not a JSON.

I tried:

```
 var inner = myJson.response;
 console.log("inner Json =", inner);                  //====1
 console.log("inner Json =", JSON.stringify(inner));  //====2
 inner = JSON.parse(inner);
 console.log("inner Json =", inner);                  //====3
 console.log("inner Json =", JSON.stringify(inner));  //====4
```

Neither of them is usable nor is a JSON.

The environment is:

- Server : NodeJS
- Framework: Angularjs
- Front-end: Ionic

I transferred a file by using $cordovaTransferFile
Since it is not $http so there is no point using $httpParamSerializer or $httpProvider.

How can I change the data inside `myJson.response` into usable JSON?

Edited: I'm sorry, the JSON is not the real data. I edited it before asking you so the syntax error is produced by me.
I have changed into something more like the real data and have already checked the syntax.
We use nodeJS to generate the JSON so definitely there should not be any syntax error in the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error here: `"{\"success\":true,\"results\":[{\"_id\":\"123123123\",\"email\":\"abcdgmail.com\",\"name\":\"Sixty\",\"data\":[{\"subname\":\"subname2\",\"subDate\":\"01011990\"}]]`

data is an array with a single object: `{\"subname\":\"subname2\",\"subDate\":\"01011990\"}`

then, data is inside another object that you are not closing:
`{\"_id\":\"123123123\",\"email\":\"abcdgmail.com\",\"name\":\"Sixty\",\"data\":[{\"subname\":\"subname2\",\"subDate\":\"01011990\"}]`

You have two *]* together.

EDIT
Corrected it will be:

```
var json = {
    "responseCode":200,
    "response":"{\"success\":true,\"results\":[{\"_id\":\"123123123\",\"email\":\"abcdgmail.com\",\"name\":\"Sixty\",\"data\":[{\"subname\":\"subname2\",\"subDate\":\"01011990\"}]}]}",
    "headers":{
        }
};
var response = JSON.parse(json.response);
console.log(response);
```

EDIT2

With new JSON:

```
var json = {
    "responseCode":200,
    "response":"{\"success\":true,\"results\":[{\"_id\":\"57907ca4dc2a4ff43c6d1300\",\"user_email\":\"testuser9@hotmail.com\",\"user_displayName\":\"auauau\",\"user_gender\":2,\"user_registerDate\":\"2016-07-21T07:41:24.748Z\",\"user_timezone\":\"-540\",\"__v\":0,\"updatedOn\":\"2016-07-22T02:20:44.624Z\"\,\"user_images\":{\"avatarSmall\":\"n/a\",\"avatarLarge\":\"n/a\",\"coverSmall\":\"n/a\",\"coverLarge\":\"n/a\"},\"user_birthDate\":{\"status\":false,\"dateAndTime\":\"1994-12-01T07:00:00.000Z\"}}]}",
    "headers":{
    }
}
json.response = JSON.parse(json.response);
console.log(json);
```

With the code above you can now use json.response as a JSON Object.

Comment: Yep, one of results is not closed.

Comment: I'm sorry about my syntax mistake. But can you look at it again? Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse not working because there is syntax error in myJson.response object.

Check following

```
{
"success": true,
"results": [
              {
                    "_id": "123123123",
                    "email": "abcdgmail.com",
                    "name": "Sixty",
                    "data": [
                               {
                                "subname": "subname2",
                                "subDate": "01011990"
                               }
                            ]
               }// this is missing in your object
           ]
}
```

Comment: I checked and I found that it was my mistake. I'm sorry, but can you look at it again? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you mean it is still not working? after syntax error solve?

Comment: yes, the syntax error is my own mistake.
Edited:  I have tried getting the inside and then JSON.parse(inner);  however, it seems that the outer { } make the innerJson act as an object thus cannot be parsed.